# Ember and window load hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

What hook can I use in ember that will only run after all of the content has been loaded?

I'm using zurb foundation's top-bar fixed and once a view is rendered I want to do something like this to dynamically space my body:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").css("padding-top", parseInt($(".top-bar").css("height")) - 2);
});
```

The closest solution I've found [here](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/) is:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },
  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    // implement this hook in your own subclasses and run your jQuery logic there
  }
});
```

This almost works except for the fact that all of the content is not yet loaded i.e. images have not yet been loaded and therefore calculation above is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the afterRenderEvent you can use some jQuery logic that waits for the image to be fully loaded

```
afterRenderEvent : function(){
  $(photo).bind('load',doSomething());
}
```